# How Do I Insert Items From An Edit Control In A Double Linked List

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi

I need to insert some data from an edit control in a double linked list.
How can i make this? The datatype of the edit control is `CString` and all are named like `m_...` for example `m_anrede` and so on...

**My struct looks like this:**

```
typedef struct adr{

    char anrede [5];
    char vorname [51];
    char nachname [51];
    char plz [8];
    char ort [60];
    char strasse [51];
    char land [24];
    char festnetz [14];
    char mobil [14];
    char mail [101];
    char geburtsdatum [11];
    char kategorie [31];
    char startnummer [5];
    char startzeit [9];
    char zeit [9];
    char rang [5];
    char fahrrad [31];
    char sponsor [31];
} adressen;


struct node{

    adressen *konto;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: *"The datatyp of the edit contol is CString"* - now that's pretty unlikely. It may be, that `CString` objects are mapped to those `CEdit` (presumably) controls. Either way, going forward, you have two options: Learn MFC, or don't use MFC. Also, there's almost no reason at all to use static character arrays instead of `std::[w]string` in C++. It violates the [Zero one infinity rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of thumb.

Comment: Ths is all a bit unclear.  Is there just one edit control with some sort of text with separators, or an edit control for each struct field?  Either way, I can't see how you can fill in all the fields easily in one OnClick/whatever handler.  It looks to me like a load of unavoidable boilerplate, unless you pack the struct and supply struct byte offsets in Tag fields, or other such nasties.  Also, wots wrong with std::deque?

Comment: No there's an edit control for every struct field. Our teacher told us to do the struct with char arrays and the datatype CString for the edit controls.

Comment: *Our teacher told us to do it this way...* You should have put that in the question. What have you tried and what problems are you having? If project is set to unicode then there is problems with unicode/ANSI conversion...

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your data structure to make it more C++ alike:

```
#pragma once

class CAddress
{
public:
    CString anrede;
    CString vorname;
    CString nachname;
    CString plz;
    CString ort;
    CString strasse;
    CString land;
    CString festnetz;
    CString mobil;
    CString mail;
    CString geburtsdatum;
    CString kategorie;
    CString startnummer;
    CString startzeit;
    CString zeit;
    CString rang;
    CString fahrrad;
    CString sponsor;
};
```

Instead of home-grown linked list I'd use MFC-standard `CList<CAddress>` or even better C++ standard container (collection class): `std::list<CAddress>`.

So in your app window header file you'll have your list defined as class member like this:

```
CList<CAddress> m_AddrList;
```

You would need some sort of method to get user input and fill in your data structure:

```
void CAddressEditorDlg::FillInAddr(CAddress& addr)
{
    m_anredeEditBox.GetWindowText(addr.anrede);
    m_vornameEditBox.GetWindowText(addr.vorname);
    m_nachnameEditBox.GetWindowText(addr.nachname);
    m_plzEditBox.GetWindowText(addr.plz);
    ...
}
```

After that you can simply add user-configured address to your list:

```
void CAddressEditorDlg::OnAddAddrButton()
{
    CAddress currentAddr;
    FillInAddr(currentAddr);
    // add new addr to linked list
    m_AddrList.AddTail(currentAddr);
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: If I were you I'd dig into `CList` source code to see how it's implemented just for educational purposes.

Comment: Either use `CList<CAddress>` or `CList<CAddress, const CAddres&>`. There's no need to have the list return modifiable objects.