# Data from Edit Control --> double linked list --> List Control

Tags: c++, struct, mfc

In my project i need to put the inserted data from an edit control in to a double liked list and then print all entries in a List Control.
My teacher told me to handle the data in a struct (so i'm not allowed to do this in a class). I put the struct in the ...Doc.h file. The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct adr
{
    char anrede [5];
    char vorname [51];
    char nachname [51];
    char plz [8];
    char ort [60];
    char strasse [51];
    char land [24];
    char festnetz [14];
    char mobil [14];
    char mail [101];
    char geburtsdatum [11];
    char kategorie [31];
    char startnummer [5];
    char startzeit [9];
    char zeit [9];
    char rang [5];
    char fahrrad [31];
    char sponsor [31];
} adressen;

struct node
{
    adressen *konto;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Every struct field has its own edit control. The edit controls got a limited amount of character. So you cannot insert to many characters for the struct fields. The datatype of the edit controls is CString and they are named like:

```
m_anrede
m_vorname
m_nachname
m_plz
m_ort
m_strasse
m_land
m_festnetz
m_mobil
m_mail
m_geburtsdatum
m_kategorie
m_startnummer
m_startzeit
m_zeit
m_rang
m_fahrrad
m_sponsor
```

The edit controls are placed in a dialog wich is named by DlgAdd.

Now i need to insert the data from the input dialog in the double linked list with the struct which is placed in the ...Doc.h file and then print all entries in a list control the wole code should be in the View.cpp file.
**I need hints and tricks to do this, thanks a lot**

Comment: Linked list is a set of nodes which know about their predecessor and successor using pointers. You need very simple pointer arithmetic to achieve desired results for search, insert and delete operations.

Comment: yes that is exactly what our teacher told us but i don't now how this works.

Comment: Why don't you use `CString` instead of arrays of `char` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Insert Items From An Edit Control In A Double Linked List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368489/how-do-i-insert-items-from-an-edit-control-in-a-double-linked-list)

Comment: It seems like you are limited to `char` arrays with a fixed size. Take a look at [`strcpy_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx). As for the double linked list - [German article](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/c_von_a_bis_z/021_c_dyn_datenstrukturen_002.htm) and [one I just found in Google.](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex32.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to make this as generic as possible to not "hurt" your learning

- you will need variables to hold the values that come from the edit boxes
- you will need to link the variables to the controls inside the DoDataExchange method
- to set the limit of characters in the edit box: look in the class CEdit there is a method for it, you will have to use it in your OnInitDialog method
- on the click of a button, you will need to create a struct using the variables that were filled by the controls and store it in your linked list
- then you will have to run through your list and use a method from the CListControl class to add the items